# I am not able to open a .tgz file on a Mac

Tags: mac, archive

I am not able to open a .tgz file on a Mac. I tried unarchiver, stock software, commander, stuffit. What can I do?

Comment: What error message did you get?

Comment: What does Get Info says about the file? Does it say "Kind: gzip compressed tar archive"?

Comment: Double-click the file.  Finder knows what a TGZ is.

Answer (score 3):

- Open Terminal
- `mkdir ~/Downloads/unpacked`
- `cd ~/Downloads/unpacked`
- Type `tar -xf`  (notice the trailing space), drag & drop the file into the Terminal window and then press Return